# How to add an Intents extension to your ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

How to add an Intents extension to your ios app

Comment: if you want to more R & d https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/CreatingtheIntentsExtension.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH4-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a built-in template for it, although I admit it needs a little work.

1. Create a regular iOS app of your chosen template.
2. Go to the File menu and choose New > Target
3. Select iOS > Application extensions from the left-hand pane.
4. Now choose Intents extension.

That will create two new groups: YourExtension and YourExtensionUI. If you open the YoureExtension group you'll see IntentHandler.swift, which contains some sample code for handling workouts. If you're just getting started, I would recommend ditching that code entirely because it's longer than it needs to be.

Here's a much simpler example to get you started:

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, INSendMessageIntentHandling {
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> AnyObject {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
        return self
    }

    func handle(sendMessage intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        print("Send message: " + (intent.content ?? "No message"))

        let response = INSendMessageIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil)
        completion(response)
    }
}
```

[I wrote about this, and other iOS 10 features, in more detail here.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/ios10)